# ERROR - TypeError: Type error only on Safari after made GET request to the api server inside angular 5 app

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, httpclient

So I am making the web app on top of angular 5.
The problem is when I try to call the api endpoint from the server.

When I get an error response (400+), it seems like on ***Safari*** it always throws and breaks the app.

```
ERROR - TypeError: Type error
ERROR CONTEXT – DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 0, nodeDef: Object, …}
```

[image]

But on ***Chrome*** it can handle the error correctly like this.

```
GET https://api.xxxx.com/projectname/v1.0/validation/access-token 400 (Bad Request)
```

This is my source code

```
const baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
const fullUrl = baseUrl + '/productname/v1.0/validation/access-token';

const headers = new HttpHeaders({
     'X-Access-Token': access_token
});

this.http.get(fullUrl, {
    headers: headers
}).subscribe((res: any) => {
   console.log(res, 'http res');
},
(error: any) => {
    console.log(error, 'http err');
});
```

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I could not remember, but if i am not wrong the reason is because of the response from the api is not on the correct format.

Comment: Thanks for replying but the same code is working on every other Android & iOS device with any OS versions. Only one specific device (iPhone 7) running iOS 12 is having this issue.

Answer (score 2):

After a lots of debugging, I figured out the issue that was causing for me. In every request, I was sending the name of the mobile device and for my case it was, **Shashank's iPhone**.

Calling [`setRequestHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader) with **single quote** in the header was failing and hence all the HTTP request broke.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `Flutter App` using an `Inapp_Webview` that points to an `Angular 1.X` web application and was also receiving a `TypeError` for all XHR requests after changing my iOS device name to include an apostrophe.

(*wanted to leave a comment, but didn't have the rep yet)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33595833)